# Windows 10: Computer switches to internal screen, messing up window sizes and positions

Tags: windows, laptop, windows-10, intel-graphics

I have a Fujitsu P772 notebook computer. It came installed with Windows 7 and I recently upgraded to Windows 10. After the upgrade, I noticed a problem whenever the screen would go to sleep by the five minute inactivity timer or right away after being locked. Moving the mouse should wake up the screen, which it does, but before that happens, Windows switches to the internal screen for a second. This causes all the windows to be resized and moved to fit the smaller internal screen size (1280 x 800 vs 1920 x 1200).

Computer specs:

- Intel Core i7-3667U
- 4 GB ram
- 64-bit Windows 10 Build 10240 OS
- Intel HD Graphics 4000

So my questions are:

1. Is there an easy way to prevent the windows from resizing when switching to the internal screen and back, or possibly to automatically restore them? (I have figured out a way to do this, but it's not so easy.)
2. Better yet, is there a way to tell Windows to not use the internal screen at all until I tell it to?
3. Is this problem likely the fault of Microsoft, Intel, or Fujitsu?

(My workaround for now is to use my phone to connect to my computer using remote desktop [at the 1920 x 1200 resolution] and then wake up and log into my computer.)

Comment: BTW, This problem didn't occur with Windows 7 (the first part of it, at least).

Comment: Maybe the monitor needs to be awakened before the computer... Just an idea.

Comment: @wbeard52 Thanks for the suggestion. I didn't know I could wake up my monitor manually. That does seem to work, but I'm still looking for a more long-term solution.

Comment: I called Fujitsu tech support and their answer was just that my computer isn't yet supported on Windows 10. They also said that there's no way to disable to internal screen.

Comment: Are your monitors identified correctly? I mean do a right click on desktop -> Screen Resolution -> Identify. You must see "1" number on your main monitor

Comment: My external monitor is 2. And I have Windows set to "show only on 2".

Comment: I am also having monitor hell with Windows 10. I have 2 screen via DisplayPorts form ATI card. One vertical and on e horizontal. The problem occurs when coming out of sleep, the screens go mental, black screen (not power saving), desktop icons rearranged each time, once this is main monitor the next time another is main monitor. From cold boots it seems to work fine... but I didnt do that in 7. It worked for more than 18 months... then Windows 10 came along and fixed it for all of us.

Comment: @ppumkin It seems like to Windows 10 might be to blame here. I'm considering moving back to 7 given that this problem might not be solved.

Comment: Its not a massive issue for me.. It seems win10 is faster for me and I like all the new notifications and app "type" stuff you can install. I am sure they will solve these issues soon- it seems like a widespread issue.. again GFX drivers and all sorts of weird combinations, screens, etc... If its not sorted by end Dec '15 then It would start to p**** me off that they ignoring us :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with Intel HD Graphics 4000 that I did the same 7 to 10 upgrade with and was experiencing similar display issues.  Earlier this week I upgraded to Windows 10 build 10525 and used the Intel driver update utility to update the graphics driver to 10.18.10.4226 (version reported in Device Manager).  These were both done on the same day so I can't say which one resolved the problem but it has since gone away.

Comment: I tried downgrading my graphics driver from 10.18.10.4252 to 10.18.10.4226, but that made no difference. So I guess I'll have t wait for Windows 10 build 10525.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Go to Control Panel -> Display -> Change display Settings

Select your secondary screen and tick 'Make this my main display'

Then in the "Multiple displays" box select 'Extend these displays'

That fixed weird flickering issues after sleep on my Win10 laptop, hope it works for you too.